# I want to create a CICD for my azure repo which has multiple projects in its subfolders

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My azure repo has multiple projects in it (it is not a single solution with multiple projects), which are placed in subfolders. How to publish artifacts separately for each of the project, which are placed in different folders.

Comment: The artifact has the path to publish -- so can you get the things you want into your artifacts into separate directories?

Comment: I was unable to add any folder name for publish path of artifacts. when I give like this $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\HelloWorld it is throwing error stating that unable to findthe path

Comment: Are your files in that directory? You can add commands like "dir" / "ls" if you can't figure out otherwise where the files are.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

By using paths include statements you can specify a build file and a trigger for each of the subdirectories.

An example below

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/Development
  paths:
    include:
    - slapi
    - slapi.Common
  batch: True
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
```

This allows each subdirectory to trigger and build to a separate output directory as needed.

In Azure Devops you then import this build YAML file to create your build pipeline and then when you create your release pipeline you select this build pipeline as the source for the drop files

Obviously you need to complete the above example file with the actual build configuration but since the question was about using subdirectories I included the relevant parts.

For your working directories use the variables section like this to specify the project at hand

```
variables:
  vmImageName: "windows-2022"
  workingDirectory: "projectName" <- change this to your real project name
```

then refer to the variables in your build task like this

```
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: Build
            inputs:
              command: "build"
              projects: |
                $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
              arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release
```

Comment: where do i need to add that paths in build task?

Comment: @Gayathri I edited my answer to include those details